# Turbolinks for Rails not active

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to get Turbolinks to work with my **Rails 3.2** app, but without success. I am still getting full page reloads in Chrome and Firefox when I click on links.

1. I have included the turbolinks gem in the `Gemfile`, and required it in the `application.js` file.
2. I should add that I run `Twitter Bootstrap 2.2.1.1`, and that all non-bootstrap/rails javascript is disabled.

In Chrome developer tools I can see that turbolinks.js is loaded, together with all other files. Any suggestions on why turbolinks is not active in my app?

Comment: Did you restart your server?

Comment: I find it strange that turbolinks.js is loaded but that it doesn't do anything.

Comment: "all non-bootstrap javascript is disabled" would explain why the JS needed to make turbolinks work isn't running.  What have you tried?  Have you checked out [Ryan Bates' Railscast on Turbolinks](http://railscasts.com/episodes/390-turbolinks).  Could we see an example of code?

Comment: @tharrison: sorry, should have been more clear, I meant other page-specific js, in this case d3.js. I have watched Ryan's railscast and followed it closely, but maybe not close enough...

Comment: I am having the same problem, running on Chromium 18 (wattOS), wondering if this is a browser version issue.

Comment: @stephenmurdoch: Might be the browsers, but I am having the same issue in Firefox as well. I am running OSX.

Comment: It is recommend to have requiring Turbolinks as the last line in your javascript manifest file, so that it is loaded last.

Comment: Try setting breakpoints in the installClickHandlerLast and handleClick functions in Turbolinks.js (lines 246 and 253 for me). Make sure that installClickHandlerLast gets called when your page loads, and that handleClick gets called when you a click a link. If they're both being called, step through handleClick and see how far you get.

Comment: Have you tried clearing your browser's cache?

Comment: Have you tried using Turbolinks.visit("path") in your browser's console? Does it work? Is Turbolinks defined?

Comment: Does Turbolink run successfully when page loading first time and start to failed after clicking a link or button?

Comment: Thank you all for the comments. Finally got it to work when I created a new gemset, still don't really know why this made it work...

Answer (score 4):

If you are using a bootstrap template, then the javascript (by default) is not placed in the `<head>` element of your page.

I was able to reproduce the issue w/ Rails 3.2.11, turbolinks 1.0 and a default bootstrap template as my application layout

If you move `<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>` from the bottom of the layout (usually just above `</body>` to somewhere within the `<head>` element, then everything should start working.

a.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I would disable bootstrap to isolate the problem first. There might be some weird problems due to that. Take a look at Yehuda Katz' blog post on Turbolinks and you'll see some of the possible problems.

However, from your post I'm unclear as to what the problem is. If it is that page-specific js isn't getting loaded, this may be because turbolinks doesn't reload :head within your rails view.

Look into calling (page:load), (page:change) as found in the Turbolinks README.md file and loading things that way? Also, with certain pages that might not be well suited to turbolinks, you can pass a data tag to disable it on that specific page.

Will

Answer (score -2):

In my case I have a strange thing:

Turbolink is working nice with firefox and safari; but it doesn't with chrome : I have a full page reload, confirmed by the network inspector.